com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: Cannot update disposition as no receive-link is established
I have a case in my application I would consume messages from ServiceBus Topic process them and saves in to DB. Here when ever I have a DB connection issue for certain time I need to OPEN an circuit and temporarily halt receiving messages from ServiceBUS, So when ever I get this message I would stop the client and sender and when circuit changes to Halfopen we restart the sender& client, till here every thing is fine but when we restarted form then onwards when I receive message I facing this exception com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: Cannot update disposition as no receive-link is established.
